# 700 x 32c Tire on 27 x 1 1/4 Wheels?

Tags: tire, wheels, vintage

I have some vintage 27 inch wheels and I was wondering if I could use some 700 x 32c Tires on them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Really doubt it.  27 is 630 iso and 700 is 622 iso. 
[SheldonBrownTireSizing](http://sheldonbrown.com/tire-sizing.html)

Comment: Thanks, I just went ahead and bought some nice 27 in tires